# How to create a new array of objects form object without duplicates ? (ES6)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, ecmascript-6

I would like to create an array of all "*department*" from the "*users*" array without duplicate in ES6.
I've tried with forEach, reduce, filter, without success...

**Users array:**

```
let users = [{
    firstname: 'test',
    department: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'hello'
    }
  },
  {
    firstname: 'test2',
    department: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'hello2'
    }
  },
  {
    firstname: 'test2',
    department: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'hello'
    }
  }
]
```

**Result expected:**

```
// Expected 
departments = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'hello'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'hello2'
  }
] */
```

My [own experiment](https://jsfiddle.net/o9pd3hra/31/):

```
let departments = []
users.forEach(user => {
  console.log('-------------------')
  console.log(departments)
  console.log(user)
  console.log(user.department)
  console.log(departments.includes(user.department))

  if (!departments.includes(user.department)) {
    departments.push(user.department)
  }
  console.log(departments)
})

console.log(departments)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post the code you say you've tried

Comment: Using [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy) from lodash might be a good solution ;)

Comment: @Finrod Thanks but I prefer vanilla in this case ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem:**

Your problem is that you are checking for departments with [`Array#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) which is rather used with primitives such as `Number` and `string` and doesn't compare `objects`, try not to use it as it's not compatible with IE also.

**Solution:**

You can do it using [`Array#map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Array#filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) methods:

```
var deps = users.map(u => u.department);

let results = deps.filter((item, pos) => {
 return deps.map(v => v.id).indexOf(item.id) == pos;
});
```

- First `map` the items to keep only the `department` object.
- Then `filter` the `departments` to exclude the ones that has the same `id`.

**Demo:**

This is a working demo:

```js
let users = [{
    firstname: 'test',
    department: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'hello'
    }
  },
  {
    firstname: 'test2',
    department: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'hello2'
    }
  },
  {
    firstname: 'test2',
    department: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'hello'
    }
  }
];

var deps = users.map(u => u.department);

let results = deps.filter((item, pos) => {
 return deps.map(v => v.id).indexOf(item.id) == pos;
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just map to the departments, then filter out based on the id:

```
  const ids = new Set;

 const result = users
   .map(user => user.department)
   .filter(({ id }) => !ids.has(id) && ids.add(id));
```

(This is O(n) as Set lookup / insertion is O(1))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for that:

```js
let users = [{
    firstname: 'test',
    department: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'hello'
    }
  },
  {
    firstname: 'test2',
    department: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'hello2'
    }
  },
  {
    firstname: 'test2',
    department: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'hello'
    }
  }
];

let departments = users.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
  let exist = acc.find(({id}) => id === obj.department.id);
  if(!exist){
    acc.push({id:obj.department.id, name: obj.department.name});
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(departments);
```